# Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland custom resolution "Adjust for TV" black bars wanted and no stretching

Tags: display-resolution, 22.04, wayland

Background: I would like to use a custom resolution for a 42" OLED in order to make the 42" even smaller. Instead of having a resolution of 3840x2160 I would like to set up 3840x1440 which should lead to black bars (top and bottom). I use an AMD 5800h (Vega 8).

In Xorg it was working.
In Wayland a custom resolution can be set with:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=DP-2:3840x1440@60"
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

But unfortunately the OLED does not show any signal and my other monitor stretches it. The option "Adjust for TV" fixes it for Xorg but it seems it has no effect for Wayland.

"Adjust for TV" can be found under: -> Settings -> Displays -> Adjust for TV

Is it a bug?
Does somebody has a solution?

Of course I could switch back to Xorg but Wayland makes good progress so far...

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same issue.  Although for me I could not get it to work with X either.   The fundamental problem IMO is that in most cases there is a "single" list of resolutions.  What is really needed is two resolutions:   1. the resolution the monitor is using, e.g. 3840x2160      2. the resolution the OS is using, in this case 3840x1440 .   And then instructions on how to map these:   scale it to fit and stretch?   center it?    The OS could use resolutions larger than the monitor and pan around or scale down as well.